# NotFoundHttpException when I try to run Codeception on Laravel 5

Tags: functional-testing, laravel-5, codeception

I am trying to play a little with Codeception in Laravel 5 and I get a NotFoundHttpException.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

1. Installed (via composer)

   ```
   "codeception/codeception": "*"
   ```
2. Ran a `vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap`
3. Edited `tests/functional.suite.yml`

   ```
   class_name: FunctionalTester
   modules:
       enabled: [Filesystem, FunctionalHelper, Laravel5]
   ```
4. Did a `vendor/bin/codecept build`
5. Created a simple functional test in `tests\functional\RegisterCept.php`

   ```
   $I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
   $I->wantTo('register a user');

   $I->amOnPage('/');
   $I->see('online');
   ```
6. Modified the terminate method of `vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Lib/Connector/Laravel5.php` with (due a bug fix research)

   ```
   public function terminate(DomRequest $request, Response $response)
   {
       $request = Request::createFromBase($request);
       $request->enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();

       $this->httpKernel->terminate($request, $response);
   }
   ```
7. Ran ./vendor/bin/codecept run functional and test fail at the set *I see "online"*

In tests\_output\ I see RegisterCept.fail.html with NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the Laravel 5 connector with the Codeception package itself, but there is a Codeception module for Laravel 5 on GitHub.

[Codeception Laravel 5 Module](https://github.com/janhenkgerritsen/codeception-laravel5)